# How do you give your users a unique ID without using the primary key in the database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, unique-index

If I have 10,000 users and the primary key is a unique ID going from 1 to 10,000, is there a way to give them all a unique ID such that the original primary key cannot be inferred from it?

For example, linking to your facebook profile or similar would be http://site.com/profile?id=293852

Is it likely that the id there is the same as the primary key of their user in the database? I am struggling to think of a way to have two unrelated unique ID columns, because randomly generated ones would have to be unique. I imagine if it were possible to have a GUID using numbers only the length would be far too long.

And ideas?

Comment: Is it a problem to have the primary key/ID visible ?

Comment: Could you create a hash of the primary key and distribute that out?

Comment: @Scorpi0: I'm not sure, do you think it is? Do you think your facebook id after profile?id= is your primary key?

Comment: In ICQ I think it was the ID... The question is : do you want to know how facebook is done, or do you really NEED this feature ?

Comment: @Scorpi0: If facebook simply used the primary key then I'd not worry about hiding it so much. I figured it was a fairly easy way to judge which way I should go with my own site.

Comment: @SLC I'm curious to know what did you end up doing? Appreciate if you could share your knowledge.

Comment: I believe I added a column with a random number in from 100000 to 999999 and I made the profile url the PK and the random number, eg. primary key id is 7, random number is 235829, profile url is 2358297. Then I just ensure the first 6 digits match the value in the random number column. The idea wasn't to hide the ID, it was just to stop someone writing a script to harvest everyone's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have generally two options:

1. As you said, use randomly generated data. (You only need to ensure they are unique, i.e. either long enough, or generate-verify-retry.)
2. Get the primary key and transform it “pseudorandomly” to something else which *seems* to have nothing to do with the primary key. The transformation might be very simple (if you want just a mild protection), e.g. `new Random(primaryKey).NextInt()`, or it might be quite complicated, but attack-proof, e.g. any kind of [Format-preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).

But then… why do you think you should protect the values of your primary keys? If the only reason is to prevent users guessing other valid user IDs, you can just append a random string to the primary key (and store it in the database and verify its correctness on access).

Comment: I like the last part, that's rather clever!

Answer (score 2):

It is really recommends in security reason to make ID non sequential, to avoid enumerating of user in system. But 4 billions (I mean 2^32) is too small to provide non-discoverable interval. That is why GUID is more preferable. Depending on database (looking at your spec it seems like MSSQL) you can store in guid-like fields, byte fields (for MySQL) or 2 separate int64.

To reduce URL size the base64 encoding can be applied so GUID looks shorter.

Answer (score 1):

How you generate the random and unique ids is a useful question - but you seem to be making an assumption about *when* to generate them!

My point is that you do not need to generate these id's at the time of creating your rows, because they are essentially independent of the data being inserted.

What I do is pre-generate random id's for future use, that way I can take my own sweet time and absolutely guarantee they are unique, and there's no processing to be done at the time of the insert.

For example I have an orders table with order_id in it.  This id is generated on the fly when the user enters the order, incrementally 1,2,3 etc forever.  The user does not need to see this internal id.

Then I have another table - random_ids with (order_id, random_id).  I have a routine that runs every night which pre-loads this table with enough rows to more than cover the orders that might be inserted in the next 24 hours.  (If I ever get 10000 orders in one day I'll have a problem - but that would be a good problem to have!)

This approach guarantees uniqueness and takes any processing load away from the insert transaction and into the batch routine, where it does not affect the user.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with allowing the user to see the primary key?

You could generate the numbers randomly, make sure it's a really big number so that clashes are unlikely, then just run a select to check it doesn't exist.

Or, you could pick a huge number, and then base some equation around that. Something like:

```
unique = 1000000000 * (-1 * PK)^3
```

That means that the unique numbers will get further away from your starting number as the PK increases, and be above or below it depending on whether the PK is odd or even. The more complexity you add to the equation, the less likely it'll be discovered, but never ever 100% rely on this method, as there is always the possibility someone will work it out.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use part of a GUID and the actual ID.

In the table I have a column type uniqueidentifier with a default value of newid()

I then take part of it and add the actual serial ID on the end with a known delimiter between them. I use the letter H as this doesn't appear in GUIDs.

So for row #8659 I would have:
IDcolumn=8659
GUIDcolumn='{200BAB55-C7D5-4456-AB57-CFF8B7E82A90}'
PROFILECODE='200BAB55H8659'

I can locate the correct row by:

```
partGUID=split(PROFILECODE,'H')(0) - gives 200BAB55
realID=split(PROFILECODE,'H')(1) - give 8659
select * from mytable where IDcolumn=8659 and left(GUIDcolumn,8)='200BAB55';
```

In theory the SQL parser should find all rows with IDcolumn 8659 first and then check for the GUIDcolumn

If people try to guess an ID for a profile they couldn't just change one part of it and succeed.